# Number format in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number for example `39.46`
and i want it to convert in `,`format i.e it should look like `39,46` in SQL

is there any function to convert decimal amount in `,` separated format ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQl Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres...

Comment: I am using ORACLE RDBMS

Comment: SQL Server or mysql or oracle

Comment: What do you mean "convert to `,` format"?  Numeric values in a table are stored in an internal representation.  You can use `to_char()` to fetch them in alternative formats.  You can also re-set the default formats for the database.

Answer (score 2):

There is a NLS setting NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS, where you can set "," as decimal separator and "." to separate thousands. They are typically automatically set when you set your locale. You obviously use an English locale.

See [here](http://www.datenbank-sql.de/nls.htm).

This assumes you have actual numbers in your DB and not strings which look like numbers. For strings you may want to use sting conversion operations as described by Thomas G.

Comment: this is actually a better answer than mine since he finally stated Oracle DBMS. since I am a fair player I upvote :)

Comment: Err..  not really. You don't **have** to use string manipulations; the string can be converted to number and then formatted using the nls_numeric_character parameter.

Comment: @mathguy do you even read? At the time I wrote my asnwer the OP had still not specified the DBMS. Anyway I removed my answer.

Comment: That is why I said your answer was wrong FOR ORACLE (I can't speak for the other RDBMS's).

Answer (score 0):

Below I demonstrate how to use the number format and the nls_numeric_characters parameter, both for a numeric input and a string input. Notice the d (or D) in the format model, it says "use whatever the appropriate decimal separator is."

```
SQL> select to_char(93.23, '999d99', 'nls_numeric_characters='',.''') from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
  93,23

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.14
SQL> select to_char(to_number('93.23'), '999d99', 'nls_numeric_characters='',.''') 
                                                                            from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
  93,23

1 row selected.
```